# How much time should I keep available an external link from a media (image, png, ...) sent via twilio message (whatsapp)?

Tags: twilio, whatsapp

I'm using Twilio platform to provide whatsapp messages. I'm saving medias on external link (S3 bucket) and I'd like to know how much time this external link should keep available on S3 for the final user get images downloadables.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your Twilio message logs, to see if Twilio is hosting the media files for you, which were pulled from your S3 bucket when you made the outbound API call?

Storing Sent and Received Pictures with Twilio Programmable SMS
https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133387-Storing-Sent-and-Received-Pictures-with-Twilio-Programmable-SMS

I Imagine it is handled in a similar manner to SMS.